# Rear disc brake question

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, disc-brake

I have a dynacraft next mountain ridge 26" bike & it already has a front disc brake but would I be able to add a disc brake to my rear wheel which previously had a v brake on it that I ripped off?

Comment: can you post us a link to that bike?

Answer (score 2):

To add a rear disc brake you must have a frame with a disc mount. You will also need a rear wheel that has a disc compatible hub. Unless you find a really good deal on something used you will spend more than the bike is worth. If you feel the rear V brakes were insufficient, your money would be better spent getting quality shoes for the rear. Some riders claim good quality V shoes work as well as low end discs.

Comment: You can get adapters for adding discs to frames with no mounts, but the precision required makes it difficult to get set up right. With good quality (parallelogram) V Brakes, pads and new cable you will out perform cheap discs. My old bike I could easily lock the rear with just my index figure.

Comment: The v brakes kept rubbing on my rim & cause me to loose speed while riding that's why I ripped it off. This is a link to the exact same bike as mine as mine is no longer sold at Walmart. http://www.jlaforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=215767461

Comment: Have you brought the wheel to your local bike shop to see if it can be trued (straightened)? It will be cheaper than a disc brake.